# How to scan a string including the Space and Tab?

Tags: c, debugging, user-input

I'm often using C code to take some input and manipulate it; for example, I want to scan a full phrase like "hello world" but as it contains a space, I find myself forced to use "gets" to include the spaces or even tabs sometimes.

Comment: [You cannot use `gets()` safely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/15168) — you should never, ever use it.  That question highlights alternatives.  Do you want to read lines, or do you have some other form of input in mind?

Comment: @Kami SM Instead use fgets.

Comment: You can use `sscanf` to parse the string after reading it in with `fgets`. Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use `scanf()` or `fgets`, just remember use the `stdin` as input stream

Comment: Do you mean one *can* use those functions? In that case, a little more detail would be warranted, especially for `scanf()`.  As far as `stdin` being an available stream, did you then mean that one can use *`fscanf()`*?